# Google Docs - Keyboard shortcut to correct a misspelled word?

Tags: google-docs, keyboard-shortcuts

In Google Docs, if a misspelled word is present in a document, a red underline is displayed under that word, as is typical in text-composition applications.

When the caret (insertion point) is positioned over the misspelled word, is there a keyboard shortcut that can be used to get Google Docs to display suggested corrected spellings (i.e. the same behavior that Google Docs provides when you right-click the misspelled word with the mouse)?

On a Windows PC, I would normally use the ["Menu" / "Applications" key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) for this; however, in Google Docs, this causes an unrelated context menu to be displayed that does not include spelling suggestions.  (Tested in both Firefox and Chrome.)

Comment: Doesn't look like it. The only keyboard shortcuts I see for misspellings just allow you move to the next/previous misspelling. I can't see a way to get the Google Docs context menu to come up with just the keyboard. Bad accessibility design if you ask me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

Works in Google Chrome for me.

I found this at https://sites.google.com/a/umich.edu/going-google/accessibility/google-documents-keyboard-shortcuts---mac

Comment: Interesting.  This shortcut only seems to work in Google Docs -- not any other applications that I tried briefly -- but it does work!  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work in *both* Firefox and Chrome - it just opens a regular context menu. Same result as using the _menu_ button that is located next to right ctrl.

Comment: Link gives a 403 forbidden error

Answer (score 5):

According to [Google Docs help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/179738?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), context menu can be opened with following keys.

<kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>

or

<kbd>Cmd / Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: On Mac, per my testing (Firefox on Mac) and also the linked article, only Cmd+Shift+\ works, but not Cmd+Shift+x.

Answer (score 4):

1. Move courser into underlined misspelled word, 
   (=> correction bubble will pop up (see image))
2. press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select,
3. press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to apply.

[image: example]

---

Based on [this answer by Miso Takacs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62446761/1870254).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thanks!

Comment: If your caret is already positioned within the word, this is the fastest way (two keystrokes, and easy keys as well).

Answer (score 1):

Hit f7 followed by enter.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, F7 is a handy shortcut!

Answer (score 1):

On a full-sized keyboard on Windows, the <kbd>Menu</kbd> key now opens the contextual `Did you mean:` menu.

The sequence <kbd>Menu</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> validates the suggest spelling. This also works if the caret is right at the beginning of the word (where <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> does not). So this is the fastest way if the caret is at the beginning of the word, and the second-fastest way if not.

If your keyboard does not have a menu key, know that <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> replicates it. So the full sequence becomes <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>: one less keystroke compared to other combinations suggested here, though admittedly the F10 key is awkwaredly placed.

[image]